# How to pass store to the sub component in react redux?

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

I am working on a react app and I created a global store

```
const store = HsGlobalStore();

class HsManApp extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <div className="d-flex flex-column bag-white">
                <Provider store={store}> <NewHsMasterNav />  </Provider>
                <div className="clearfix"></div>
                <div className="container-fluid hs-fix-nav-content ">
                    <Router>
                        <Provider store={store}> 
                            <Route path="/" exact component={HsHome} />
                            <Route path="/:pageName" component={HsPage} />
                        </Provider>
                    </Router>
                </div>
            </div>
           
        );
    }
}


const id = "hs_welcome_root";

ReactDOM.render(<HsManApp />, document.getElementById(id));

export default HsManApp;
```

and I am passing this store by Provider to the Master page components

```
<Provider store={store}> 
                            <Route path="/" exact component={HsHome} />
                            <Route path="/:id" component={HsPage} />
                        </Provider>
```

But this Man components also have sob components

```
class HsHome extends React.Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

    }



    render() {
        return (
                <div className="row">
                    <NewHsAvatarBox /> 
                </div>
        );
    }
}

export default HsHome;
```

Now. how can I pass this store to this  component?

Comment: I don't think you actually want multiple providers, just wrap the whole thing in one. Then use the [`connect` HOC](https://react-redux.js.org/api/connect) or [hooks](https://react-redux.js.org/api/hooks) to access it in sub-components.

Comment: @BrianThompson your comment becomes Answer for me. Thank you so much for your help :)

Answer (score 0):

You need "decorate" your component, passing the store to props

```
import { connect } from 'react-redux';

class MyComponent extends React.Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        console.log(this.props.name);
    }
    ...
}

const mapStateToProps = (store) => {
   // console.log('store', store);
   return {
      name: store.<reducer>.name,
   };
};

export default connect(mapStateToProps, null)(MyComponent);
```

then use the name exported in mapStateToProps as props in MyComponent